# Rails Michael Hartl Tutorial + Devise current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to implement the follow actions from M. Hartl's tutorial in my rails composer, devise app.

But for some reason i get this error

```
undefined method `current_user?' for
```

when using this code

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Have you defined `current_user?` anywhere? I think devise has `current_user` and `user_signed_in?` methods, but not the one you're using. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Please give the chapter no.

Comment: mind.blank, i've already check that link and the method it gives for current_user is the same as in my code

@bapusethi, Listing 11.23.

Comment: Please note "current_user' and current_user?" are not the same methods.

Comment: Yes but by using just current_user (instead of current_user?) i get this error => wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: @user2225129 this error wrong number of arguments (1 for 0) means that the method doesn't take no arguments and your feeding it an argument which from the looks of it is `@user`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devise gives you the `current_user` helper by default. However, it doesn't give you `current_user?` boolean method. You need to define this method yourself in `application_helper.rb`:

```
def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end
```

Now you have `current_helper?` defined you can pass in your `@user` instance variable

```
<% unless current_user?(@user) %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Thats all you have to do. You don't have to touch your `ApplicationController or SessionsHelper` in any way. You are simply using `current_user` which Devise gives you in order to define `current_user?(user)`. This way is much easier to implement. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Hopefully you should have the following setup:

Your `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  include SessionsHelper

  # Force signout to prevent CSRF attacks
  def handle_unverified_request
    sign_out
    super
  end

   private
    def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
    end
     helper_method :current_user

  def authorize
    redirect_to login_url, alert: "Not Autherized" if current_user.nil?
  end

  def track_activity(trackable, action = params[:action])
    current_user.activities.create! action: action, trackable: trackable
  end
end
```

You should also have a `sessions_helper`

```
module SessionsHelper
  def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    self.current_user = user
  end
  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end
  #CHECK THE ABOVE LINE! 
  def sign_out
    self.current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Then you can do in your view the following:

```
   <% unless current_user?(@user) %>
      <div id="follow_form">
      <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
        <%= render 'unfollow' %>
      <% else %>
        <%= render 'follow' %>
      <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I've changed that but now i get this error => undefined method `following?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Your problem here is that the variable following is most likely to be empty when you get this error. Where exactly are you setting `following` ?

Comment: but still cant get "current_user?(@user)" to work! So frustrating! 
And if i use your code given above they're errors with the <% if current_user %>

Comment: what controller is this view responding to ?

Comment: relationships_controller and users_controller

Comment: I don't see why you keep doing `current_user?(@user)`. If you set in your controllers `@user = current_user` then you can just `<% unless current_user %>`.

Comment: I added it to the controller but im still getting the error! undefined method `current_user?'

Comment: Because the form doesnt appear