# NoMethodError in Application#angular devise current_user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to build a follow user feature in my app using [Railstutorial.org](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#cha-following_users) and I'm hitting a error that doesn't make a lot of sence to me.

In my applicaion.html.haml I render 2 partials,

```
= render '../assets/javascripts/angular-app/templates/stats'
= render '../assets/javascripts/angular-app/templates/follow_form' if user_signed_in?
```

The first partial (stats) is this,

```
- @user ||= current_user
.stats
  %a{:href => following_user_path(@user)}
    %strong#following.stat
      = @user.following.count
    following
  %a{:href => followers_user_path(@user)}
    %strong#followers.stat
      = @user.followers.count
    followers
```

And resolves without error,

The second partial is this,

```
- unless current_user?(@user)
  #follow_form
    - if current_user.following?(@user)
      = render 'unfollow'
    - else
      = render 'follow'
```

And throws an error, `NoMethodError in Application#angular`

```
Showing /home/alucardu/sites/movieseat/app/assets/javascripts/angular-app/templates/_follow_form.html.haml where line #1 raised:

undefined method `current_user?' for #<#    <Class:0x007fbe544651f8>:0x007fbe64cdbb10>
```

I'm using Devise for my registration and user handeling.

On my application.html.haml I have

```
.welkom
  Welkom
  = current_user.name
```

And this hows my first and last name and in the first partial I also use `current_user` so why am I getting the error `undefined method`current_user?'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails Michael Hartl Tutorial + Devise current\_user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797816/rails-michael-hartl-tutorial-devise-current-user)

Comment: Yup looks the same, the answers there helped me out. Thanks for he input.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `current_user?` method in devise, if you want to check whether there's a current user or not you can use `user_signed_in?` method